# Dependency Injection Approachh Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

So Far, I've figured out two ways to inject services

Method A:

```
public function __construct($entityManager, $mailer, $templating,$notificationManager,$taskManager,$leadNotificationManager,$dealNotificationManager,$taskNotificationManager) 
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->em = $entityManager;
    $this->templating = $templating;
    $this->notificationManager = $notificationManager;
    $this->taskManager= $taskManager;
    $this->leadNotificationManager = $leadNotificationManager;
    $this->dealNotificationManager = $dealNotificationManager;
    $this->taskNotificationManager = $notificationManager;

}
```

in that case I'll use the service as below

```
$this->mailer->send($message);
```

Method B:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) 
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

and use it as below

```
$this->container->get('crm_sandbox_google_calendar')->markDone($entity)
```

method A looks more specific, but it limits the dependancy as Serivce A cant Include service B if service B includes service A [cycle]

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first pattern is called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (and in your case specifically *Constructor Injection*), while the other pattern is the exact opposite, namely [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

There are so many downsides to the Service Locator pattern, that it is [generally considered to be an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: So how do I fix the issue when two services need to use each other using dependancy injection ?

Comment: @SelfSayed you change the design. Cyclic dependencies aee a design smell and is usually caused by a Single Responsibility Principle violation. The typical solution is to extract part of the logic into a new class that both old classes can depend on.